# Eslint and Prettier on VSCode change any space on my JSX code to {' '} in React Native project

Tags: reactjs, react-native, visual-studio-code, eslint, prettier

I am frustrated about this issue, i did install eslint and prettier and did the config for them. but i had this issue. they change every space on my code to {' '}

example before lint the code

```
<Text style={styles.smallText}>
1 {base} = {rate} {quote} as of {moment(date).format('MMM DD, YYYY')}
```

after lint

```
<Text style={styles.smallText}>
s 
{' '}

{base}
{' '}
=
{' '}
{rate} 
{' '}
{quote}
{' '}
as of
{' '}
{moment(date).format('MMM DD, YYYY')}
  </Text>
```

=======

my configration is like this :
1- Run npm install -g eslint
2- run eslint --init
3- Select "Use a popular style guide"
4- Select "Airbnb"
5- Do you use React? y
6- What format do you want your config file to be in? JSON

my .eslintrc.json file

```
    {
  "extends": "airbnb", // EXISTING
  "parser": "babel-eslint",
  "env": {
    "browser": true
  },
  "plugins": [
    "react"
  ],
  "rules": {
    "react/jsx-filename-extension": [
      2,
      {
        "extensions": [
          ".js",
          ".jsx"
        ]
      }
    ],
    "react/forbid-prop-types": [
      0
    ],
    "react/require-default-props": [
      0
    ],
    "global-require": [
      0
    ]
  }
}
```

7: added those scripts to package.json

```
  "lint": "eslint app/",
  "lint:fix": "eslint app/ --fix"
```

8: added those to my VSCode settings

```
 {
  "prettier.eslintIntegration": true,
  "editor.formatOnSave": true
}
```

i tried a lot of fixes but i cant fix it.
thanks

Comment: is using template literal not an option? It'll avoid that without additional config. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: @TanKimLoong yes this is an option thanks man